# How To Generate Full Width Responsive SubMenu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here i am trying to generate full width responsive submenu for service li in my menu but i am not able to generate the full width responsive submenu.
A example of full width submenu i am trying to generate is this.[image]

And my current submenu for service by my code is show as :[image] 
Below is my code

```
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <h1><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
      </a>                    
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="scroll dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Service <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at it, but I'd need to see the CSS. I found the free template, but the it doesn't have a dropdown menu. So if I could see your CSS, I could get back to you and see what I can do! :)

~ Daniel

Ps I couldn't comment, rep is less than 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can find full-width responsive menus here:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

scroll down to see more.

You must use some framework, in this case it's bootstrap.
if you want to keep your code, provide us full-codesnippet or a jsfiddle link, otherwise seem that you want us to create all css/js over your html (and some people will offend and downvote your answer).

Hope it helps!